# Set object properties after setting the object

Tags: class, object, properties, vb6

I've created a class with various properties in VB6.

The properties are

`PiccoId`
`OrderId`
`UserId`
`StockCode`
`Quantity`

At the top of the class I have declared 2 instances of classes I'm using.

```
Dim stkLine As CSOPSLine ' This is the class where the properties are declared and read
Private SOPSLines As cSLine ' This class creates the new objects and sets the property values
```

When the user enters the order number on a handheld barcode scanner, I'm creating an object to associate with this particular scanner like so:

```
Set SOPSLines = New cSLine
Set SOPSLines = getSOPSLine(ID, sOrder, "", "", 0)
```

In the next stage of the process, the user needs to enter their user ID so it can be seen which user scanned in the item.

I need to update the property of this same object, but I'm not sure how - Currently I am trying to do it within my `getSOPSLine` function, like this:

```
Dim line As New CSOPSLine
Dim bFound As Boolean

bFound = False

For Each line In SOPSLines.Items
   If line.PiccoId = ID Then
     line.OrderId = OrderId
     line.Quantity = Qty
     line.StockCode = stock
     line.UserId = UserId

     Set getSOPSLine = line
     bFound = True

     Exit For
   End If
Next

If bFound = False Then
   Set line = SOPSLines.Add(ID, OrderId, UserId, stock, Qty)
   Set getSOPSLine = line
End If

Set line = Nothing
```

However, as I'm not storing `sOrder` at class level (Due to the fact multiple users can be using barcode scanners, the order ID can't be kept at class level as other users will just overwrite it),

I'm not sure how once I've got the next variable (In this case, `userID`, and the other variables after this stage) I can update the same object as I've just created.

I've tried to do something like

```
Set stkLine = getSOPSLine(ID, stkLine.OrderId, pUser, "", 0)
```

but it errors saying

> object or with block variable has not been set

How can I update the properties of `stkLine` without constantly creating new objects?

**EDIT**

To clarify:

When the application receives data from the handheld barcode scanner, a select case is entered, with one case for each of the variables being entered (E.g. Order ID, user ID, stock code etc.)

The first case sets the order ID.

The code here is

```
Case FRAME_ORDER_SELECTION
On Error Resume Next

    Dim sOrder As Long
    sOrder = Picco.GetData(ID, 50)

    If sOrder = 0 Then
        Call Picco.Send(ID, FRAME_ORDER_SELECTION)
        Exit Sub

    Else
        With Picco
            Call .ClearForm(ID)
            Call .Text(ID, LINE_1, "===== User ID =====")
            Call .Text(ID, LINE_2, "")
            Call .NewField(ID, 60, 5, FLD_LINE + SND_ENTER)

            Call .Send(ID, FRAME_LINE_ADD)

            Set SOPSLines = New cSLine
            Set SOPSLines = getSOPSLine(ID, sOrder, "", "", 0)

        End With
    End If

    frameid = FRAME_LINE_ADD
    m_iLastFrameId = FRAME_ORDER_SELECTION

    On Error GoTo Picco_DataArrived_Err
```

This is where the object is created.

The next case is after the user enters their user ID into the scanner.

```
Case FRAME_LINE_ADD

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim pUser As String

    pUser = ""
    pUser = Picco.GetData(ID, 60)

    If pUser = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error GoTo Picco_DataArrived_Err

    With Picco
         Call .ClearForm(ID)
         Call .Text(ID, LINE_1, "===== Add Line =====")
         Call .Text(ID, LINE_2, "")

         Call .Text(ID, LINE_7, "Scan or type code")
         Call .NewField(ID, FIELD_POS, 18, FLD_LINE + FLD_READER + SND_ENTER)
         Call .Send(ID, FRAME_LINE_QTY)
End With

    Set stkLine = getSOPSLine(ID, stkLine.OrderId, pUser, "", 0)

    frameid = FRAME_LINE_QTY
    m_iLastFrameId = FRAME_LINE_ADD
```

Then there will be 2 or 3 more cases when populating the rest of the required values.

What I need to do, is in the second case (And all other following cases) update the properties of the object created in the first case.

I'm using the getSOPSLine function as this gets the object with the matching barcode scanner ID (As multiple users may be accessing different orders, they need to be kept separate in this way), but I'm not sure how to update the object where the scanner ID matches.

Comment: The code block you posted: Set SOPSLines = New cSLine followed by Set SOPSLines = getSOPSLine(...) doesn't make sense. The first statement creates an object. The second statement immediately replaces that object with another one. You don't need the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `getSOPSLine` in each Case, enter some temporary values for the variables that you're not setting.

Example;

In the UserID case: `stkLine = getSOPSLine(ID, 0, pUser, "", 0)`

Then, in the `getSOPSLine()` function, change it so that instead of setting the values automatically, it instead only updates them if they don't equal 0, or "", or whichever temporary variables you use.

That way you're updating the same object, but aren't storing data that may get overwritten.

Comment: There is an easier way and better way to do it, but this is a work around in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're confused about; I think that you must have some misunderstanding of what objects, variables, and properties are that is preventing you from asking this in a way that I understand. I'm not sure how your code lines up with your questions. But I'll give this a shot:

> ```
> Private SOPSLines As cSLine
> Set SOPSLines = New cSLine
> Set SOPSLines = getSOPSLine(ID, sOrder, "", "", 0)
> ```

This declares a class-level variable, that can hold a cSLine object. That seems reasonable. Then you create a new instance of cSLine to put in that variable. But I don't know why, because you then point the variable to a different instance entirely, which is the instance returned from your getSOPSLine function. That middle line doesn't seem to be doing anything, and I'm not sure what you're trying to do with it.

> I've tried to do something like
>
> ```
> Set stkLine = getSOPSLine(ID, stkLine.OrderId, pUser, "", 0)
> ```
>
> but it errors saying
>
> > object or with block variable has not been set

Well, then it sounds like `stkLine` isn't set to an object. I don't see any code that's trying to set stkLine other than that line. So when you try to get `stkLine.OrderId`, there isn't an object to get the OrderID property of, so it gives you an error.

> I need to update the property of this same object, but I'm not sure how

Well, if there's an object you care about, you probably have it in a variable somewhere. You use `variable.property = value` syntax to assign *value* to the *property* of the object currently stored in *variable*.

But again, I'm not sure where your confusion is, since you're clearly assigning properties of objects in your code already.

If you're not understanding how objects work in VB, I'd recommend reading through the [Working with Objects chapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa232713%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) of the documentation.

And if your confusion lies elsewhere, perhaps you could put together a more specific question about what you're trying to do?

Comment: In response to your first point, the middle line is there to create a new instance of the variable, as without it an error is returned. The structure of this code is that when the application receives data back from the handheld barcode scanner, it goes to a select case, with each case being the data that is being entered (user ID, order ID etc). Let me quickly update the question to make this more clear.

Comment: @David I think a lot of your confusion is that you're changing class-level variables both inside `getSOPSLine` and outside of it. Instead of updating class-level variables, just pass around the values that you want modified. And step through your code with the VB6 debugger to understand what each line is doing; it's a pretty nice debugger.